# Cleanup with 'replace' not working as intended - Pandas

Tags: regex, dataframe, replace

I've tried to apply the 'replace' method on this list in a dataframe:

df=pd.DataFrame({'DC': ['DOUBLE CHANCE\n1 OR X\n**2.50**\nX OR 2\n**1.12**\n1 OR 2\n**1.20**']})

Desired result: `2.50\n1.12\n1.20`

Looking for suggestion to make the cleanup work either 'replace' method or 'regex'

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'DC': ['DOUBLE CHANCE\n1 OR X\n2.50\nX OR 2\n1.12\n1 OR 2\n1.20']})

df = df['DC']['Double_Chance'].str.replace(r'([^\d\.\n])','').str.replace(r'1\n','').str.replace(r'2\n','').str.replace(r'12\n','').str.strip()
df
0       2.50\n1.111.20
Name: Score, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.replace`:

```py
df['Double_Chance'] = df['DC'].str.replace(r'(?m)^(?!\d+\.\d+$).*\n*', '')
```

Or, you may use `Series.str.findall`:

```py
df['Double_Chance'] = df['DC'].str.findall(r'(?m)^\d+\.\d+$').str.join("\n")
```

Both produce `2.50\n1.12\n1.20`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ryaLKq/1). Details:

- `(?m)` - the `re.M` option that makes `^` match start of each line
- `^` - start of a line
- `(?!\d+\.\d+$)` - fail the match if the line is a float number
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\n*` - zero or more line feed chars.

Comment: Awesome. This works on the fly! Learning regex on the go...any best place or source to learn?

Comment: @stephen.m Since a lot of people ask me about that, I [wrote this post](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/wstribizew/my-regex-road-so-far). Scroll to the last paragraph.